# C# WriteProcessMemory strange stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm using WinAPI function WriteProcessMemory from kernel32.dll to write to another process' memory.
It worked good for a few times, but then it just stopped working correctly.

I'm importing this function with this code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

And here's code that I'm using to write:

```
int bytesWritten;
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (IntPtr)dwAdress, data, (uint)size, out bytesWritten);
```

It just throws this exception:

> System.OverflowException
>
> Debug info:
>
> [debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGxxz.png)

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: This is not a stack overflow exception. `System.OverflowException` is raised on arithmetic or cast overflow. Do you create 64-bit application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your p/invoke is declared incorrectly. The final two parameters are `SIZE_T`, which is pointer sized. Your code should be:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess, 
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress, 
    byte[] lpBuffer, 
    UIntPtr nSize, 
    out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

Note that `SIZE_T` is an unsigned type, hence the use of `UIntPtr`. If using an unsigned type is not convenient you could switch the above to use `IntPtr` instead since you are never going to write more then 2<sup>63</sup> bytes.

The code that you presented does not test the return value of `WriteProcessMemory`. Please always checked return values for errors. For instance:

```
if (!WriteProcessMemory(...))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Win32Exception said that I'm writing in incorrect address. Ofcourse, like usual. I already hate C#. Moving to C++

Comment: That problem is with your code. The code in this answer is accurate.